# differentiating equations with expectations

Tags: probability, derivatives, game-theory

I'm reading the following [paper](http://www.kellogg.northwestern.edu/faculty/schummer/ftp/research/bbribe/bbribe2.pdf) about bribing and signaling in second price auctions, and having some difficulty in understanding some parts.

On page 8 they develop the following formula which describes when will bidder $j$ try to bribe bidder $i$

$$F(A)(θ_j − b) + \mathbb{E}_{θ_i} [(θ_j − θ_i)_{(A<θ_i≤θ_j )}]\ge \mathbb{E}_{θ_i} [(θ_j − θ_i)_{(θ_i≤θ_j )}$$

which I understand, but then he wants to show the group $\mathbb{B}$ is an interval, so he wants to show that if the equation holds for some $θ_j$ it will hold for any $\hat{θ_j} \lt θ_j$.

So he differentiate both sides with respect to $θ_j$ to get

$$\frac{\partial LHS(θj )} {\partial θj}
= max\{F(A), F(θ_j )\}\ge F(θ_j ) = \frac{\partial RHS(θ_j )}{\partial θ_j}
$$

This is the part I dont understand, how do u differentiate that equation? and how do you get this result?

moreover, I'm trying to extend this result to the case of 3 players, so I have the equation

$$F^2(A)(θ_j − 2b) + \mathbb{E}_{θ_i, θ_k} [(θ_j − max\{θ_i, θ_k\})_{(A<max\{θ_i,θ_k\}≤θ_j )}]\ge \mathbb{E}_{θ_i} [(θ_j − max\{θ_i, θ_k\})_{(max\{θ_i,θ_k\} ≤θ_j )}$$

How can I differentiate this equation?

Comment: I think where you say "derive" you mean "differentiate" (i.e. form the derivative)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that both differentiation and expectation are linear operations, so we can interchange them if the RV is integrable (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217702/when-can-we-interchange-the-derivative-with-an-expectation)).

To get you started with an informal derivation, consider the RHS:
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j} \mathbb{E}_{\theta_i} \left[ (\theta_j-\theta_i)\, \mathbb{I}\{ \theta_i \leq \theta_j\} \right] = \mathbb{E}_{\theta_i} \left[ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j} \left( (\theta_j-\theta_i)\, \mathbb{I}\{ \theta_i \leq \theta_j\} \right) \right]
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j} (\theta_j-\theta_i)\, \mathbb{I}\{ \theta_i \leq \theta_j\} &= \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j} (\theta_j-\theta_i)\, \times \mathbb{I}\{ \theta_i \leq \theta_j\} + \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j}\mathbb{I}\{ \theta_i \leq \theta_j\} \times (\theta_j-\theta_i) \\
&= \mathbb{I}\{ \theta_i \leq \theta_j\} + 0 = \mathbb{I}\{ \theta_i \leq \theta_j\}
\end{align}
where we're being a bit loose with differentiating the derivative of the indicator (not treating the case $\theta_i=\theta_j$, in which case we might want something related to differentiating the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function#Antiderivative_and_derivative)).

Now we have 
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}_{\theta_i} \left[ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_j} \left( (\theta_j-\theta_i)\, \mathbb{I}\{ \theta_i \leq \theta_j\} \right) \right] = \mathbb{E}_{\theta_i}\left[ \mathbb{I}\{ \theta_i \leq \theta_j\} \right] = \mathbb{P}\left[ \Theta_i \leq \theta_j \right] =: F(\theta_j)
\end{align}
from the definition of $F$ as a CDF earlier in the paper. Note also that I switched to upper case $\Theta$ to denote it as a RV.

Comment: what does RV stands for? also, by following the same logic on the LHS, we have two summand, the  derivative of the first one is $F(A)$ and the sceond one is   $\mathbb{P}\left[ A \leq \Theta_i \leq \theta_j \right] =: F(\theta_j) - F(A)$
so adding them up gives me $F(θ_j)$ . How did they get $max\{F(A), F(θ_j)\}$

Comment: Sorry, i meant RV for "random variable". Let me take a look again tomorrow morning

Comment: Roughly, the case you give assumes $\theta_j > A$. Depending on the relationship between $\theta_j$ and $A$, we can have the RHS be $F(A)$ (i.e., if $\theta_j \leq A$). So we either have $F(A)$ or $F(\theta_j)$, though I agree that this could be made more explicit...