# How does one usually evaluate the expected value of observed Fisher information?

Tags: fisher-information

How does one usually evaluate the expected value of observed Fisher information?

That is what does

$$\mathcal{I}(\theta)=-E\left[\frac{\partial^2}{\partial\theta^2}l(X,\theta)\mid\theta\right]$$

evaluate to?

Particularly, how is $E$ treated? How does $E$ apply to the derivatives?

Comment: Usually in an exercise you calculate the quantity inside the expected value (thus the derivatives of the maximum likelihood estimator) and then you use the information given (distributions of variables and estimation rules) to calculate it.

Comment: @Rebellos That's observed Fisher information? I'm asking expected.

Comment: There's a lemma which allows interchanging derivatives and $E$: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1986477/248602

Comment: If the quantity within brackets is a random variable, where is the issue with taking expectation of that quantity as usual?