# The central moments of stochastic differential equations

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations, moment-problem

How can one look at the evolution of covariance matrix using Ito lemma for a non-linear stochastic differential equation? when the stochastic term is a Brownian motion?
$$
d\mathbf{X(t)} = \boldsymbol{F(X,t)}\, dt + \mathbf{G(X,t)}\, d\mathbf{B}
$$

$$
\frac{d}{dt}Cov(X, X) = ?
$$
when $Cov(X, X) = \langle X^2 \rangle - \langle X \rangle^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We apply Itô lemma to $Y_{t}=(X_{t}-\mu_{t})^{2}$

$$dY_{t}=2(X_{t}-\mu_{t})dX_{t}-2(X_{t}-\mu_{t})d\mu_{t}+d[X]_{t}$$

$$=2(X_{t}-\mu_{t})dX_{t}-2(X_{t}-\mu_{t})d\mu_{t}+G^{2}dt.$$

So taking expectation leaves us with

$$Var(X_{t})=E[Y_{t}]=\int E [2(X_{t}-\mu_{t})F]dt-\int E[2(X_{t}-\mu_{t})]d\mu_{t}+\int E[G^{2}]dt,$$

where the Itô-integrals disappeared because they have mean zero [Itō Integral has expectation zero](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/232932/it%c5%8d-integral-has-expectation-zero).

So it remains t compute $\mu_{t}=E[X_{t}]$ and its t-derivative. To justify here swapping expectation and derivative, you can use [When can we interchange the derivative with an expectation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217702/when-can-we-interchange-the-derivative-with-an-expectation). Since the F,G are unknown, this is as far as we can go.