# ODE for mean of SDE

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-differential-equations

Given a stochastic differential equation

$$ dX_t = f(t,X_t) dt + \sigma(t,X_t)dB_t$$

where $B$ represents standard Brownian motion, if I wanted an ODE for the mean of the SDE, I could write for any $T > 0$

$$ X_T = X_0 + \int_{0}^{T}f(t,X_t)dt + \int_{0}^{T}\sigma(t,X_t)dB_t $$

then by taking expectation on both sides and since the integral with respect to $B$ is a martingale and has mean zero, one has

$$ \mathbb{E}(X_T) = \mathbb{E}(X_0) + \mathbb{E}\left(\int_{0}^{T}f(t,X_t)dt\right). $$

My question is, when can one exchange the expectation and integral with respect to $t$ to obtain
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\mathbb{E}(X_t) = \mathbb{E}(f(t,X_t)) $$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When can we interchange the derivative with an expectation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217702/when-can-we-interchange-the-derivative-with-an-expectation)

Comment: If you want an ODE for the mean $\mathbb E[X_t]$ you want a lot more than just exchanging expectation and integral. What properties must $f$ have so that you can pull the expectation inside it?